# Mean Size Calculation

Tags: estimation, sampling

I have a fishing survey where i'm exploring a zone with surface 3000 km².  fishing points are randomly selected within this area and in each fishing point i have a total fish number of some species and total weight. To calculate the mean weight in all the zone, i get some issues because i used a method and my colleague uses another one which gives different results.
My way is that i estimated the mean weight based on the sample (easy). But for my colleague he tries to estimate the total weight in all the zone and the total number in all the zone given the surface and after he divides the weight by the numbers.
Can you please help me to understand which method is correct and why.
Regards

Comment: The second method is more appropriate. The mean weight by definition is the total weight over total number. By right since you are finding weight and number of many zones, the better sample with smaller variance in fact is the total of all zones not the the individual zone.

Comment: My concern is that his total weight and numbers are just extrapolations and he estimate the mean weight based on those estimations. Thats why i thought that using the observed sample values supposing that it's a good image of the population will be more correct.

Comment: Oh my bad. Then it's better if you construct confidence intervals based on your smaller samples.